# Kendo Grid Client Template with Condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

```
 columns.Bound(p => p.Active).ClientTemplate("\\#if('#=Active#'=='Y') {\\<input type='button' value='OK' />\\}\\#").Width(150).Title("Status");
```

but condition is taken as  string??

```
#if('Y'=='Y')`enter code here` {
<input type="button" value="OK">
}#
```

Answer (score 34):

There are three ways to use the hash syntax in a Kendo template:

1. Render literal values: `#= #`
2. Render HTML-enocded values: `#: #`
3. Execute arbitrary JavaScript code: `# if(...){# ... #}#`

So in your code you would have to write

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Active).ClientTemplate(
     "#if(Active=='Y') {#
        <input type="button" value="OK">
      #}#").Width(150).Title("Status");
```

Notice in the sample how the `#` signs separate **inside** code from **outside** code. When you're inside code you don't have to use `#` again to access a variable and that's why Active can be without `#` before.

Comment: Do you know how to do it with external template( in a script file)? My template is too complicated to put it inside the clienttemplate...

Comment: I think this should work... columns.Bound(p => p.Active).ClientTemplate("# myfunc(data) #");

Comment: This was useful in getting my blank values in a template sorted: thanks.

Comment: If I wish to write also the else condition?

Answer (score 8):

Try this,

```
 columns.Bound(p => p.Active).ClientTemplate(
                "# if (IsServiceExist) { #" +
                    "<input type='button' value='OK' />"+
                "# }#").Width(150).Title("Status");
```

Comment: What it would it be if I want multiple conditions?Like: if (IsServiceExist && !IsEmail). Is the the proper way?

Comment: @Metaphor Yes you can do this in ClientTemplate

Comment: it really help me. thanks jaimin. come to my site http://translateyar.ir

Answer (score 7):

I hope you get the solution....

```
columns.Bound(p => p.IsActive)
    .ClientTemplate(
        "\\# if (IsActive != false) { \\#" +
            "\\<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkBox\" class=\"parentCheckBox\" window-call=\"template\" checked/>\\" +
        "\\# } else { \\#" + 
            "\\<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkBox\" class=\"parentCheckBox\" window-call=\"template\" />\\" + 
        "#\\ } \\#")
    .Width(10);
```

Answer (score 5):

To have data values rendered in your Kendo template you could use the following as a guide:

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>)
    .ClientTemplate("#if (Field3 == true) {#"
    + "<a onclick='jsFoo(#=Id#)' href='\\#'></a> "
    + "#} #").Width(70).Title("ColA");
```

Comment: this one is better than original answer

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me but note do not use href='#' it will break the template compiler.

```
 c.Bound(p => p.ItemNumber)
  .Width(64)
  .ClientTemplate("# if (ItemCommentActive) { #" +
                      "<a href='void(0);' title='#=Comments#' onclick='return false;'>#=ItemNumber#</a>" +
                       "# } else { #" +
                       "<div>#=ItemNumber#</div>" +
                       "# } #");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
columns.Bound(searchModel => searchModel.Value).ClientTemplate(
    "#if(Name=='DevboardTask'){# " + 
        "<a href='\\#UpdateStatusWindow' onclick=\"javascript:openflexpmtask('#=Value#');\">#=Value#</a> " +
    "#} else {# " +
        "<a\">#=Value#</a> " +
    "#}#");
```

This might help you. This is just an example...